# how to take inside array count in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hi all i am using `angularjs` i have one object inside some of data now i need to take the count of an a object array here i attached my code help how to do this

```
$scope.data = {
    "label": "Information",
    "fields": [{
      "name": "name",
      "label": "Team Name",
      "type": "string",
      "config": {}
    }]
 }
```

here i want take `fields` count or length

Comment: Is `data` coming from a REST call? Which version of angular? You want to get length from controller or from template?

Comment: it's scope variable i update my question @sabithpocker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`fields`** is an **`array`** inside the data, so you could just use **`length`**.

```
var fieldscount = data.fields.length;
```

**EDIT**
Since you need the count  of fields inside the object, you can just use **`Object.keys`**,

**`Object.keys(data.fields[0]).length`**

**DEMO**

```js
var data = {
    "label": "Information",
    "fields": [{
      "name": "name",
      "label": "Team Name",
      "type": "string",
      "config": {}
    }]
 }
 console.log(Object.keys(data.fields[0]).length);
```

Comment: i need fields count i need output 4@Sajeetharan name,label,type,config total 4 i need